# Replace final comma in a string with ' & ' - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, replace

I am trying to replace the final comma (`', '`) in any given string with `' & '`.

I do not want to use any regex.

Is there some method I can use that fulfills the following psuedo-code:

```
find last x in string
replace last x with y
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid regexps?

Comment: you didn't show us your try ..?

Comment: A regex solution is `"See no evil, hear no evil, speak no evil.".sub(/.*\K,\s/, ' & ') #=> "See no evil, hear no evil & speak no evil."`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sub` method replaces only the first occurrence, so you can `reverse`, `sub` and `reverse` again.

`"Ruby on Rails, Ruby, String, Replace".reverse.sub(',', '& ').reverse`

Comment: Same idea, but you were a bit faster... ;-)

Comment: @mtaff I'm glad to help. If it worked for you, please could you Accept it?

Comment: @mtaff you do realise this solution still used a regex.  By definition sub looks for a pattern (read regex) which is then replaced.  So according to your own words, this is not an acceptable solution

Comment: @grail I presumed that the objection to regex was because of it's poor readability.

Comment: @SekalfNroc I am not picking on your solution at all :)  Just reminding the OP that he asked for a non-regex based solution

Comment: @grail, in Ruby's documentation, "pattern" is not a synonym for "regular expression". If (one form of) a method takes an argument that must be a regular expression (e.g., [Regexp::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#method-c-new)), the doc uses "regexp", rather than "pattern".  For [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-sub), a "pattern" can be a string or a regular expression. Many Ruby methods have an argument that is a "pattern". I can't think of a case where "pattern" refers to anything other than a string or regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

A one-pass solution:

```
>> "Lions, tigers, bears".tap{|s| s[s.rindex(', '), 2] = ' & '}
=> "Lions, tigers & bears"
```

- `tap` assigns a variable name to the string literal inside of it's block. This isn't necessary if the string already has a name assigned to it.
- `rindex` finds the last occurrence of its argument in the string its called on.
- `s[idx, len] = str` replaces the `len`-lengthed substring in `s` at position `idx` with `str`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using capturing groups around the last comma:

```
>> "one, two, three, four".gsub(/(.*),(.*)/, '\1 &\2')
=> "one, two, three & four"
```

These groups will match around the last `,` because the first capturing group (the first `(.*)`) is greedy. `.*` will match as much text as possible which means it will match up to the last `,`, then the second capture group `(.*)` will match what is left.

The replacement string (`'\1 &\2'`) then places the capture group text around a `&`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
string = string.rpartition("&").map do |x|
    if x == "&"
        ","
    else
        x
    end
end.join("")
```

works?

Comment: I think `gsub` replaces all occurrences. However, I just want to replace the last occurrence